# Separate vertically elements with space between in Material UI drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've implemented the following drawer using Material UI (left side of the picture). I want to stick to its bottom the last element in the drawer, as shown in the right side of the picture. In order to do so, I've tried many approaches like using a `Grid` component, a `Box`, and `div`s with `flex-box` parameter, but nothing worked. How can I achieve that? At the moment, my implementation for the drawer content is somethinkg like this:

```
  <Grid container spacing={0} direction="column" alignItems="start" justify="space-between" alignContent='space-between'>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Divider />
      <CardHeader
        ...
      />
      <Divider />
      <List>
        <...>
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        <...>
      </List>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Divider />
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            Z
          </Avatar>
        }
        title="ZaraHealth"
        subheader="v. 0.1"
      />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

[image: left: what I got; right: what I want]

Any comment will be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox is the solution. Here is a simplified version with simple divs so you can map this solution to yours

```css
.sidebar {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px); // if topbar is 60px in height
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="top-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="bottom-nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked quite well Zohaib! Thanks! However, there is still a caveat: if I set the height of the parent div to `100vh` it doesn't consider the height of the top appbar and it generates some overflow which leads to the drawer bein scrollable. Is there any way to consider the appbar? I tried to adjust by hand the height (e.g. `92vh`), but the proportions are different in the mobile version of the site and it's not possible to make it look good in both desktop and mobile.

Comment: @pitazzo Don't hardcode hieght , use `calc(100vh - 60px);` if 60px is height of topbar. You can use media queries to set different height based on the height of top bar. I've updated the answer